# How to convert a msys shell script into a windows exe file

Tags: c++, shell, mingw, msys

Is there a generic way to convert a shell script under MSYS/MinGW into a windows `.exe` file (which calls the shell script behind the scene)?

The specific problem I am facing is that I have a shell script `lein` from Leiningen (clojure tool chain). I installed it to the default path at `/usr/local/bin` (note: I used the shell script version for MSYS, and didn't want to install `lein` command outside the MinGW/MSys tree).

Now emacs cider cannot pick up the `lein` script although `lein` is on the windows path and `exec-path`. If I copy `lein` into a fake `lein.exe`

```
cd /usr/local/bin && cp lein lein.exe
```

then, `cider` recognizes `lein.exe`. But of course, `cider` couldn't load it because it's not a valid `exe`.

Hence, my question. Is there a generic way I can convert a shell script like `lein` into a windows executable, e.g. by writing a proxy c++ program?

Thanks.

-- EDIT ---

(Thoughts after seeing the downvotes).

I know this is a corner case and maybe not something you do everyday, and but this is the best solution I can identify so far for making a workable clojure tool chain in MinGW/MSYS.

Comment: Like other questions asking "is there a way to do X" this one is too broad.

Comment: As you originally posed it, I didn't think this question was too broad at all; quite the opposite, in fact, and I might have offered an answer to that question. Now you've changed its scope entirely, to something which I would have no interest whatsoever in addressing.

Comment: @KeithMarshall, if you can post or outline a potential answer, I will roll the question back. I don't really think my question was broad either or care that others think it's too broad. I've narrowed it down only because I am interested in seeking a solution. And a more general solution for MinGW/MSYS is certainly better in my book.

Comment: @KeithMarshall Could you help edit my question to the original form you saw? I couldn't find a way to rollback my own edits.

Comment: I don't have sufficient privilege to do any more than _suggest_ edits, so no, I can't really help you with that. If you click the [edited x hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30768671/revisions) link below the question you should see the full editing history; your original question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30768671/1)

Comment: Your specific case isn't really a _corner_ case; more like just one specific example of a more generally useful technique, (and I've answered in that more general sense). I don't know why this is attracting down votes; IMO, they are unwarranted.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe my language is bad:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You originally asked this under the heading "How [can I] convert an MSYS shell script to a Windows .exe?"  In my opinion, that's a generally more useful (and quite specific) question to ask, than what you are now asking. On this basis, I will offer an answer to the original question.

I know of no way in which you can simply *compile* an MSYS shell script, (or indeed *any* Bourne shell script), into a Windows executable, such that it may be invoked as a child of another executable. However, what you may be able to do is invoke the MSYS shell itself, as the child process, to interpret the script; the syntax you need is:

```
sh.exe -c 'script [argument ...]'
```

so, if you can configure your emacs clojure process to invoke the command in this fashion, you *may* achieve your objective.

A word of caution, however: MSYS commands are intended to be run from within an already running, and properly initialized MSYS parent shell. If emacs is running as a child of such a shell, then this should work okay. However, if emacs is running as a purely native Windows process, outside of an MSYS environment, then *you* have to take care of initialization[*], when you invoke the child shell. If you see error messages such as *"resource unavailable"*, *"resource temporarily unavailable"*, or *"cannot reserve space for cygwin's heap"*, (yes, MSYS is derived from an early cygwin release, and the text of this message was never changed), that's a fairly certain indicator that the shell environment is not properly initialized.

[*] Effectively, you need to reproduce the initialization steps which are performed by the msys.bat command script, which accompanies any MSYS installation.